# How to add a sum to my SQL query?

Tags: c#, sql

I'm using this query in Visual Studio. I want to add another column which sums the fields I found (`History`, `Acts`, `Forms` and `Documents`) as a `Total` for every worker. I tried to add Sum but it didn't work well.

How can I do that?

```
sqlcmd.CommandText = "use odlight select e1.fullname as worker,acts,forms,documents,history from opg.dbo.vwemployee as e1 " +
                     " left outer join (select tsCreatedBy ,count(actid) as acts from hozactions as h1 where ((h1.tscreatedate between '" + date1 + "' and '" + date2 + "' ) or (h1.tsModifydate between '" + date1 + "' and '" + date2 + "')) group by tsCreatedBy ) as t1 on e1.UserID= t1.tsCreatedBy " +
                     " left outer join (select tsCreatedBy ,count(*) as forms from TikForms as t1,SysForms as s1 where t1.FormCounter=s1.Counter and t1.actioncounter in ('0','-1') and tsCreateDate between '" + date1 + "' and '" + date2 + "' group by tsCreatedBy ) as t2 on e1.UserID=t2.tsCreatedBy " +
                     " left outer join (select tsCreatedBy,count(*) as documents from Documents where createDate between '" + date1 + "' and '" + date2 + "' group by tsCreatedBy) as t3 on e1.UserID=t3.tsCreatedBy " +
                     " left outer join (select tsCreatedBy,count(*) as history from nispah where tscreatedate between '" + date1 + "' and '" + date2 + "' group by tsCreatedBy) as t5 on e1.UserID=t5.tsCreatedBy " +
                     " where e1.DepartmentCode not in (6,2,4,10) and e1.Active =1 order by e1.fullname ";
```

Comment: Never concatenate strings to create sql queries. it's a security hazard. use parameterized queries instead.

Answer (score 0):

Do you want to display the sum or the count ?
I think you would need to do something like below :

```
select worker, count(History), count (document), count(acts), count(forms) 
from ....
group by workers
```

You will also need to  use a group by function :

http://sql.sh/fonctions/agregation/sum

Comment: I want to display the count (as i wrote in the query) and add another left outer join at the end of the query which sum all the fields i counted before.